# using two domains for the same email address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, mx-record, google-workspace

I have  two domains , firstdomain.com and seconddomin.com. both are registered on go daddy with custom name server.

each one of them has a hosted zone created with the route 53 service of amazon.

firstdomain.com is also having an MX records that using G suite emails from google. this mean that I am currently able to send emails to user@fristdomain.com successfully.

is there anyway to make the seconddomain.com as an alias to the firstdomain.com for the MX records. **which mean that how can make it possible if i send email user@seconddomain.com the it will go to user@fristdomain.com?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you must configure on amazon the Google MX records.

Them in the Google Admin console (admin.google.com) go to domains. And if you add as an alias domain all user should have their address of both domain.

For example you user user@fristdomain.com will receive the mails also from  user@seconddomain.com and if you create a new user called  user2@fristdomain.com is going to receive the mails from  user2@seconddomain.com